# how to show current data of datagridview in crystal report in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I want to show my current data of datagridview in crystal report. To do this I took two button, first button click fill the data in datagridview. And I want on second button click this data display in crystal report. first time I'm using crystal report and don't know to handle it. I've tried much but can't do so. on second button click I put the following code.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText);
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                dRow[cell.ColumnIndex] = cell.Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ds;
    }
```

I get following error on last line.

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Report Viewer will only show an actual Crystal Report. You can't just fill a dataset and then try to show it in the viewer, that's how a  the data grid works but not a Crystal Report. You will have to create a Crystal Report, use your data as the source and then display the fields within the report. Then you specify the report file as the datasource for the viewer.

Hope that helps,

Chris